# How to use Puppeteer to take Screenshots of Pages that Contain Video

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I'm currently using Puppeteer to open a site and take a screenshot of a video. However, the default Chromium browser that puppeteer runs doesn't work with video types.

I launched with a local version of Chrome with Puppeteer and everything is working.

Is there a way to open an actual chrome browser instance with puppeteer without having to specify a local link to the .exe to make it more scalable and less reliant on a directory when being hosted?

Puppeteer 2.0.0

**Note:** I'm running a non-chromium instance with Puppeteer (without a directory to Chrome.exe)

Comment: Perhaps your local version of Chrome has video codecs, while the headless version does not. For example, when I install Chromium on Ubuntu, I also install a package called `chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra`. This is just a guess.

Comment: I think it's just an issue with Chromium, quite a lot of people have said that they don't support video with this

Comment: I feel like a docker container is required here that contains both the executable and the script with the modules

Answer (score 2):

You may find that Puppeteer does not behave as expected when controlling pages that incorporate audio and video. (For example, [video playback/screenshots is likely to fail](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/291).) There are two reasons for this:

- Puppeteer is bundled with Chromium — not Chrome — and so by default,
  it inherits all of [Chromium's media-related limitations](https://www.chromium.org/audio-video). This
  means that Puppeteer does not support licensed formats such as AAC or
  H.264. (However, it is possible to force Puppeteer to use a
  separately-installed version Chrome instead of Chromium via the
  [`executablePath` option to `puppeteer.launch`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions). You should only
  use this configuration if you need an official release of Chrome that
  supports these media formats.)
- Since Puppeteer (in all configurations) controls a desktop version of
  Chromium/Chrome, features that are only supported by the mobile
  version of Chrome are not supported. This means that Puppeteer [does
  not support HTTP Live Streaming (HLS)](https://caniuse.com/#feat=http-live-streaming).

**Source:** [FAQ: What features does puppeteer not support?](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#q-what-features-does-puppeteer-not-support)

Comment: So i'm currently trying to execute my puppeteer request using a cloud function wherein there is no local path for me to store the executable. Do you recommend a docker container for this?

Comment: @Rake146 : I'm not sure. If you're not getting these screenshots from headless Chromium, it wouldn't surprise me if you'd ultimately need to setup a full virtual machine instead of a container. For example, will Chrome even run (without being headless) in a container that has no GUI/Desktop (to the degree that it can screenshot videos that aren't actually being displayed anywhere)? Try it and let me know; I'm curious to know what you end up doing.

Comment: @Rake146 : I found this [docker image](https://github.com/buildkite/docker-puppeteer), but have not used it myself.

Comment: Great, I actually ended up writing and using my own docker image, this solution ended up working! Thank you for the insights! Upvoted your answer!